# .bat Error: 'http:' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: batch-file, wsdl, asmx, command-prompt

I've come across another dead end in trying to SET UP, let alone run, a Unit Test from an existing ASP Web Site using Visual Studio 2012/2013, but I thought this question merited a question of it's own since, although I've seen similar questions asked, everything I've tried for the past 5 hours has yielded something between 0 and Null (not literally, that would be helpful if I would get such output),

The contents of my batch file were, following the instructions of sitepoint.com's Creating and Consuming .NET Web Services in 5 Easy Steps:

```
wsdl /l:CS /n:WService /out:bin/wsdlWalkthrough.cs
http://localhost/webserv.asmx?wsdl
```

Since I'm trying to follow the steps of an article that's over a decade old, syntax and conventions may easily have changed. But hey, it was able to guide me through making a working **.asmx** page, so I've tried to stick with it. Anyways, when I run makeWS.bat on the Developer Command Prompt for VS2012, I get the error:

> 'http:' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program, or batch file.

In attempting to fix the problem, my makeWS.bat page currently looks like:

```
wsdl /l:CS /n:WService /out:bin/wsdlWalkthrough.cs
http://localhost:20141/webserv.asmx?wsdl
```

Also, the **.asmx** file looks like this:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="GetInfo" %> 

using System; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Services; 

[WebService(Description="My Suppliers List Web Service")] 

public class GetInfo : WebService  
{
  [WebMethod(Description="My WebService",BufferResponse=true)] 

  public DataSet ShowSuppliers (string str)  
  { 

    SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("server=(local);uid=sa;pwd=;database=Northwind;");  

    SqlDataAdapter objCommand = new SqlDataAdapter("select ContactName, CompanyName, City, Phone from Suppliers  where Country = '" + str + "' order by ContactName asc", dbConnection); 

    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    objCommand.Fill(DS);
    return DS;
    dbConnection.Close();
    dbConnection = null; 

  } 
}
```

When I run the ASMX page in Firefox from File Explorer, I got the error:

> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

However, running the **.asmx** page from VS2013 got everything to work smoothly. I thought maybe the localhost port might have played a factor, so I tried adjusting my batch file:

```
wsdl /l:CS /n:WService /out:bin/wsdlWalkthrough.cs
http://localhost:20141/webserv.asmx?wsdl
```

I tried turning **Autorun** off, I've added the http addresses as **System Variables**, but nothing has worked. Is anyone out there able to identify my issues because I was honestly incredulous when my **Developer Command Prompt for VS2012** said it didn't recognize **http:**. Isn't **Hyper Text Transfer Protocol** integrated at the architectural level by now?

***UPDATE***

> > 'http:' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.
>
> is because the url is on a different line than the
>   [wsdl(.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.100).aspx)
>   command (whose argument it should be), and the batch consists (this is
>   a simplified view) of a series of commands each on a different line.
>   In order to get over this, merge the 2 lines into 1:
>
> ```
> wsdl /l:CS /n:WService /out:bin/wsdlWalkthrough.cs http://localhost:20141/webserv.asmx?wsdl
> ```
>
> or escape the *eoln* (`\r\n`) char by **^**(caret):
>
> ```
> wsdl /l:CS /n:WService /out:bin/wsdlWalkthrough.cs ^
> http://localhost:20141/webserv.asmx?wsdl
> ```
>
> and if everything is OK, you should have your *bin/wsdlWalkthrough.cs*
>   file generated.

CristiFati's instructions got me past the initial hurdle. Now the new error is:

> Error: There was an error processing
>   'http: //localhost/webserv.asmx?wsdl'.
>   -There was an error downloading 'http: //localhost/webserv.asmx?wsdl'.
>   -The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.

This seems like something I could probably find the answer to myself, but further help would still be very much appreciated.

Comment: I am not a WSDL expert, but the _.asmx_ content looks OK. Note that in your latest error messages (not sure if this isn't a typo while pasting the message) there's an extra space between __http:__ and __//localhost__. Is that error coming from the batch file? Can you try with the same link that was throwing: _XML Parsing Error: not well-formed_ in the browser? Also if you get the error in the browser can you view the page source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'http:' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.

is because the url is on a different line than the [wsdl(.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.100).aspx) command (whose argument it should be), and the batch consists (this is a simplified view) of a series of commands each on a different line. In order to get over this, merge the 2 lines into 1:

```
wsdl /l:CS /n:WService /out:bin/wsdlWalkthrough.cs http://localhost:20141/webserv.asmx?wsdl
```

or escape the *eoln* (`\r\n`) char by **^**(caret):

```
wsdl /l:CS /n:WService /out:bin/wsdlWalkthrough.cs ^
http://localhost:20141/webserv.asmx?wsdl
```

and if everything is OK, you should have your *bin/wsdlWalkthrough.cs* file generated.

Comment: How embarrassing, the New Line character wreaks havoc yet again. If I had the prerequisite reputation points, I'd give you an up-vote for that. That fixed the first issue.

Comment: Here is the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/45fez2a8(v=vs.100).aspx) link stating how to access a web service from browser:

Comment: I'm not sure how the WSDL is deployed, might be accessed by: `http://localhost:20141/webserv.asmx/ShowSuppliers?str=SomeCountryName`.

Comment: You have my sincerest gratitude for the help, I'd give you a helpful flag to go with that up-vote if I could. Sadly, all I can do is share some of my  cookies:

__cfduid __hstc __qca acct hsfirstvisit hubspotutk

Comment: You're welcome. Don't worry :). One mention though: don't include an answer (even if partial) in the question, it makes it longer (harder to read).